# Template for ISBN-10 and ISBN-13 check

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function for checking either ISBN-10 or ISBN-13 numbers:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template <int Size>
bool check_isbn(const std::string& isbn)
{
    std::vector<int> digits{};
    const auto& check_char{*(isbn.end() - 1)};
    auto check_digit = check_char == 'X' ? 10 : check_char - '0';
    std::transform(isbn.begin(), isbn.end()-1, std::back_inserter(digits), [](const auto& c) {return c - '0'; });
    auto end_digit_it = std::remove_if(digits.begin(), digits.end(), [](const auto& digit) {return digit == '-' - '0'; });
    if(end_digit_it - digits.begin() != Size-1) return false;

    int modval{0};
    int sum{0};
    if(Size == 10) {
        modval = 11;
        int factor{10};
        sum = std::accumulate(digits.begin(), end_digit_it, 0, [&factor](auto& sum, const auto& right) { return sum += factor-- * right; });
    }
    if(Size == 13) {
        modval = 10;
        int factor{3};
        sum = std::accumulate(digits.begin(), end_digit_it, 0, [&factor](auto& sum, const auto& right) {
            factor = 4 - factor; return sum += factor * right; });
    }

    auto new_check_digit = (modval - sum % modval) % modval;
    return check_digit == new_check_digit;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nISBN10 Check:\n";
    std::vector<std::string> isbn_numbers{
        "0321992784", "99921-58-10-7", "9971-5-0210-0", "960-425-059-0",
        "80-902734-1-6", "85-359-0277-5", "1-84356-028-3", "0-684-84328-5",
        "0-8044-2957-X", "0-85131-041-9", "0-943396-04-2", "0-9752298-0-X",
        "0321992384", "99921-52-10-7", "9971-5-3210-0", "960-422-059-0",
        "0-683-84328-5", "0-8024-2957-X", "0-85331-041-9", "0-949396-04-2",
        "0-9722298-0-X", "03216992784", "999621-58-10-7", "9971-56-0210-0",
        "0-80644-2957-X", "0-865131-041-9", "0-9463396-04-2", "0-97526298-0-X"
    };
    for(const auto& isbn : isbn_numbers) {
        std::cout << isbn << "\tis " << (check_isbn<10>(isbn) ? "ok" : "not ok") << '\n';
    }
    std::vector<std::string> isbn13_numbers{
        "978-0-306-40615-7", "978-0-30h6-40615-7", "978-0-306-40*615-7",
        "978-0-3076-40615-7", "978-0-3086-40615-7", "978-0-303-40615-7"
    };
    std::cout << "\nISBN13 Check:\n";
    for(const auto& isbn13 : isbn13_numbers) {
        std::cout << isbn13 << "\tis " << (check_isbn<13>(isbn13) ? "ok" : "not ok") << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following during compilation: `warning C4127: conditional expression is constant`

Full message:

```
1>  main.cpp
1>path\main.cpp(21): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
1>  path\main.cpp(51): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool check_isbn<10>(const std::string &)' being compiled
1>path\main.cpp(26): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
```

Is there a good way to avoid this warning?

Comment: What line generates the warning?

Comment: C++1z static if? But tbh, this looks rather over-engineered. Why does this have to be a template in the first place? Just switch on the length of the input at runtime.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good point. Runtime switch [works better](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e879c167c9f52427).

Comment: Supposedly, compiler tells you that you do not need to check that Size is equal to 10 or 13, because it always equals to 10 or 13 in your code. Hence, the usage of an overloaded function is more optimal here.